# Xamarin Forms CustomMapRenderer iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms

Currently working on getting custom pins to work in maps on both Android and iOS, while it is currently working on Android I am experiencing a null exception in the code immediately below (full custom renderer further down) in my custom renderer on iOS and I am struggling to figure out what is causing it.

```
    CustomPin GetCustomPin(MKPointAnnotation annotation)
    {
        var position = new Position(annotation.Coordinate.Latitude, annotation.Coordinate.Longitude);
        foreach (var pin in customPins)
        {
            if (pin.Pin.Position == position)
            {
                return pin;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I have copied the code from the Xamarin sample provided at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin/ and the sample applies the custom pin correctly.

My custommaprenderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomMap), typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]
namespace WorkingWithMaps.iOS
{
    class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer
    {
        UIView customPinView;
        List<CustomPin> customPins;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                var nativeMap = Control as MKMapView;
                nativeMap.GetViewForAnnotation = null;
                nativeMap.CalloutAccessoryControlTapped -= OnCalloutAccessoryControlTapped;
                nativeMap.DidSelectAnnotationView -= OnDidSelectAnnotationView;
                nativeMap.DidDeselectAnnotationView -= OnDidDeselectAnnotationView;
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
                var nativeMap = Control as MKMapView;
                customPins = formsMap.CustomPins;

                nativeMap.GetViewForAnnotation = GetViewForAnnotation;
                nativeMap.CalloutAccessoryControlTapped += OnCalloutAccessoryControlTapped;
                nativeMap.DidSelectAnnotationView += OnDidSelectAnnotationView;
                nativeMap.DidDeselectAnnotationView += OnDidDeselectAnnotationView;
            }
        }

        MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, IMKAnnotation annotation)
        {
            MKAnnotationView annotationView = null;

            if (annotation is MKUserLocation)
                return null;

            var anno = annotation as MKPointAnnotation;
            var customPin = GetCustomPin(anno);
            if (customPin == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
            }

            annotationView = mapView.DequeueReusableAnnotation(customPin.Id);
            if (annotationView == null)
            {
                annotationView = new CustomMKAnnotationView(annotation, customPin.Id);
                annotationView.Image = UIImage.FromFile("pin.png");
                annotationView.CalloutOffset = new CGPoint(0, 0);
                annotationView.LeftCalloutAccessoryView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromFile("monkey.png"));
                annotationView.RightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);
                ((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).Id = customPin.Id;
                ((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).Url = customPin.Url;
            }
            annotationView.CanShowCallout = true;

            return annotationView;
        }

        void OnCalloutAccessoryControlTapped(object sender, MKMapViewAccessoryTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            var customView = e.View as CustomMKAnnotationView;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customView.Url))
            {
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new Foundation.NSUrl(customView.Url));
            }
        }

        void OnDidSelectAnnotationView(object sender, MKAnnotationViewEventArgs e)
        {
            var customView = e.View as CustomMKAnnotationView;
            customPinView = new UIView();

            if (customView.Id == "Xamarin")
            {
                customPinView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 200, 84);
                var image = new UIImageView(new CGRect(0, 0, 200, 84));
                image.Image = UIImage.FromFile("xamarin.png");
                customPinView.AddSubview(image);
                customPinView.Center = new CGPoint(0, -(e.View.Frame.Height + 75));
                e.View.AddSubview(customPinView);
            }
        }

        void OnDidDeselectAnnotationView(object sender, MKAnnotationViewEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!e.View.Selected)
            {
                customPinView.RemoveFromSuperview();
                customPinView.Dispose();
                customPinView = null;
            }
        }

        CustomPin GetCustomPin(MKPointAnnotation annotation)
        {
            var position = new Position(annotation.Coordinate.Latitude, annotation.Coordinate.Longitude);
            foreach (var pin in customPins)
            {
                if (pin.Pin.Position == position)
                {
                    return pin;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Link to my repository: https://github.com/Mortp/CustomMapPinsXamarin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your custom pin is missing ID required here:

```
annotationView = mapView.DequeueReusableAnnotation(customPin.Id);
```

Need:

```
var pin = new CustomPin
            {
                Id="Xamarin",
                Pin = new Pin
                {
                    Type = PinType.Place,
                    Position = new Position(55.240121, 10.469895),
                    Label = "Testing Pins"
                }
            };
```

also instead of

```
 if (annotation is MKUserLocation)
                return null;

 var anno = annotation as MKPointAnnotation;
```

use

```
var anno = annotation as MKPointAnnotation;
if (anno == null)
     return null;
```

because annotation can be something else as you can see below.

Also, I found out that the code below (using MoveToRegion in this event handler)  creates problems with this renderer because GetViewForAnnotation starts receiving parameters other than MKPointAnnotation but cast protection above saves it from crashing. Another problem with code below that if your pin location is far from your real location you will not see the custom pin and locator tracker will always put your map into your location. To debug your pin location in such case just comment out "Move" line as below.

```
maplocator.PositionChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var position = e.Position;

                //map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(position.Latitude, position.Longitude), Distance.FromKilometers(2)));
            };
```

The function OnReverseGeocodeButtonClicked will crash soon :-) because your class member pin is  not assigned.

```
warning CS0649: Field 'MainPage.pin' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null
```

Comment: Terribly sorry about the wrong code! Not entirely awake when I posted the question, it's fixed now though. Thank you for all the feedback.

Comment: Even with your changes I am still getting a null reference whenever the pin comes into view.

Comment: More specifically it is now claiming my customPin list is null

Comment: If you have teamviewer I could try to take a look on your machine. It works on mine. Otherwise, just debug it and see why it is not initialized..

Comment: Thanks but as this is a work computer I think it would be frowned upon! I've run into a new problem anyway that ends up trivializing this one.

Comment: Got it to work, I discovered I have a lot to learn about threading as some other code needed for the label means my pin is inside an Async Task that was never called, thus no pin.

Comment: next time you should post link to your code that you are using so we can reproduce. I guess the link you posted on github don't have that call because it works